# How Do I Set a Default Property globally in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I can't see where the docs explain this.

`this.notifications.setDefaultClearNotification(value);` globally.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to set a property globally?

http://stonecircle.github.io/ember-cli-notifications/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set it within the `application.js` route in a `setupController` hook.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend( {
    setupController(){
        this.notifications.setDefaultAutoClear( true );
        this.notifications.setDefaultClearNotification(1200);
    }
} );
```

What I wasn't clear on was that it needed to go inside of a hook inside of a route/component/controller/service and also that `setDefaultAutoClear(true)` needs to be called first. It's not in the docs other than implying to use it if you want to use it's default value.

Answer (score 1):

this plugin uses a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/tutorial/service/) that is injected into [everything](https://github.com/stonecircle/ember-cli-notifications/blob/master/app/initializers/notifications.js):

```
['controller', 'component', 'route', 'router', 'service'].forEach(injectionTarget => {
  application.inject(injectionTarget, 'notifications', 'notification-messages:service');
});
```

So `this.notifications` is just always the same singleton.